# Proper Password Management with React/Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security, redux

I have a general industry question that I cannot seem to find any detailed information on. When utilizing React and Redux to create a user authentication system, is it safe from a security standpoint to store the user's entered password in the associated Redux reducer?

To be more specific, while a user is entering their password, is it safe to store their input in the redux reducer (to, on form submission, send a request to the server to authenticate said user)? If not, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe to put input password to redux store or any other place in the JS context.

Redux store is inside your browser's JS context, and everything inside browser's javascript context is strictly protected by the browser. No one can access your JS context except your code itself, not even if your page is embed inside some other page.

The only exception is browser extensions, and if anyone have access to your JS context, they can also access to the DOM, which means they can also just get the value out of your input even if you don't put the password anywhere in JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any redux dev-tools there is no problem,if u have remove it before build and producting,but you can use Md5 for hashing password ,that will be safe